# Prove that the span of $\pmatrix{4 \\ 0}$ and $\pmatrix{0 \\ -1}$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have a problem that says...

Show that $span((4,0),(0,-1))=R^2$

I have been working on this problem and this is what I have so far...

Let **m** $ =(4,0)$ and **n** $ =(0,-1) $then

$c1(4,0) + c2(0,-1) = (x,y)$

$(4c1, 0c1) + (0c2, -c2) = (x,y)$

$4c1+0c2=x ----> c1=x/4$

$0c1-c2=y  ----> c2=-y$

I understand that a span is the set of all linear combinations for vectors, but I'm not sure if I'm proving this right? I feel like I've shown the span is in $R^2 $ but I also feel like my proof is incomplete. Is this how you do this problem? If not, could you please explain.

Comment: There are several ways to solve the problem, but yours is indeed a correct one. Why did you think your solution was incomplete?

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is basically correct. You have shows that you can write any vector $\pmatrix{x \\ y}$ as a linear combination of the two vectors given:
$$
\pmatrix{x \\ y} = \frac{x}{4}\pmatrix{4 \\ 0} + (-y)\pmatrix{0\\ -1}.
$$
Do indeed the two vectors span all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you are writing this down (in for example a homework asignment), then you might start the proof by saying "Let $\pmatrix{x \\ y} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be given."

Another way you can make the arguments (this depends on what you already "know") is to say/show that the two vectors are linearly independent. *Two* linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ will span all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.